# In Ruby, how can I organize large amounts of data for most effective regex search?

Tags: ruby, regex, database, search

I am writing an algorithm that at some stage has to search several million strings using regex.

Usually I use indexed databases like Mongo or SQL to search large amounts of data, but this time I am limited to text files or hashes/arrays only.

I was wondering if there exists an effective way to organize searching of such data, perhaps something analogous to indexes in databases. As of now, my idea is to split the data into many separate text files (based on string length etc), but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Why don't you store these strings in a database before? You will save a lot of memory and you will delegate search tasks to the dbms (that is designed for that).

Comment: Did you already think of using elasticsearch? I have no experience with indexing text files with it, but i think that should be easily possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- If the data is free-form text, there's no good way to organize it short of using a tool like Elastic Search and spending a lot of time setting it up to understand your data. That step would negate any possible savings if this is a one-time job. It could be a major win if you have to do this regularly/constantly.
- If you choose to do this in a scripting language like Ruby, don't consider any solution that uses `read` or `readlines` or that does any form of "slurping" of the data as that's not scalable and can be much slower than line-by-line IO using `foreach`.
- It's possible and easy to use Ruby to read a file containing millions of lines without any preprocessing. Ruby's support of regex is good, but poorly written regex can drastically slow the speed. Examine whether you can use sub-string searches as they're the fastest, followed by anchored regex followed by unanchored regex.
- Consider using `grep` or `egrep` from the command-line. They're written to do what you want and are battle-hardened tools used on millions of systems around the world hourly for just this task. It's easy to wrap Ruby around them to control what they're going to do and grab their results.

I have answers on SO showing benchmarks for regex vs sub-string searches, and slurping vs. line-IO.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run external programs? I'd recommend you to organize your data as a text files and use [`the_silver_searcher`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) - it works similarly to grep, but is [much much faster](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher#whats-so-great-about-ag) and fully supports Perl regular expressions.